# Unity Error: Missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build my game on WebGL in unity3d v5.4.0f3 and I'm getting this error:

> errorCS-0246:The type or namespace name 'MovieTexture' could not be
>   found. Are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?

Here's the c# code :

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine.UI;


[RequireComponent (typeof(AudioSource))]

public class videoplayer : MonoBehaviour {

    public MovieTexture movie;
    private AudioSource audio;

    void Start () {

        GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = movie as MovieTexture;
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audio.clip = movie.audioClip;
        movie.Play ();
        audio.Play();

    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your build target (in Player Settings)?

Comment: i dont know,how do i know it ?

Comment: Sorry, it's in Build Settings, not Player Settings. There's a dropdown labeled **Target Platform**

Comment: ohh,sure,but this dropdown Target Platform is in PC,Mac and Linux Standalone.I'm tryng to build on WebGL

Comment: if i build on pc,mac and linux standalone it works

Comment: MovieTexture is not supported on WebGL.  It's not defined in the assemblies included in that build target. Thus the error.

Comment: oh,what should i do ? do you know any solution ?

Comment: I haven't used this, but it may work for you: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38369

Answer (score 0):

The error specifies the type/namespace "MovieTexture" cannot be found. This is likely due to a "using" statement being missing.

If you are building to a non-desktop platform, that feature/package may be unavailable on your target platform. I would verify if it actually is available, and if so, try to import the assets for it into your project. Otherwise, you may need to find a workaround.